# How to return query results from Google Sheets Custom Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a custom function that needs to do the equivalent of

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(url, xpath), query)
```

I found https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage where section "*Setting the Query from JavaScript*" nicely explains to do this with:

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(DATA_SOURCE_URL);
query.setQuery('select dept, sum(salary) group by dept');
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
```

But, I have a problem:

As shown there, `query.send()` passes the results asynchronously. But, I need to return them from my custom function. I want to show the results in the cell.

Short of writing some awful kludge with shared variables and timers waiting for results, I don't see how this can work.  What am I missing?

To summarize: I want to write a custom function that returns the result of a query to its cell in Google Sheets.

UPDATE ADDED LATER:

Several commenters did not understand my question above, so I'm adding some more details here [@tanaike, @RemcoE33 - I hope this helps]:

The following line is valid in a Google Sheets cell.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&$A5, "//*"), "select Col2 where Col1 = 'name in native language' and Col2 is not null")
```

It works. But, I need to do embed this inside a more complex calculation, so I want to move it into a custom function.

I don't see how to do this cleanly because:

1. `query.send` completes asynchronously
2. Custom functions return the value to put in the cell
3. Custom functions do not have permission to write into other cells

Therefore, I don't see any clean way of doing this other than what I called above "writing some awful kludges with shared variables and timers waiting for results".  The answer in the comment by @doubleunary is an example of this kind of solution. I will do this if I have to, but I'm really hoping for a cleaner, non-polling solution, especially because I may need to run this in many cells in parallel.

Comment: There are third party libraries like alasql that let you use sql query.

Comment: It is unclear why you would need to write a custom function to do the same thing as `query()` and `importxml()`, but try declaring a private `handleQueryResponse()` function within the custom function. Then use `while(noResponse);` to wait until `handleQueryResponse()` sets the function top-level variable `noResponse` to `false`. Finally, return the value of another function top-level variable that was set by `handleQueryResponse()`. Note that custom functions can only run for 30 seconds.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the docs. This is for querying a google sheet via the google sheets api in a 3th party app. Not to query a external csv (as example). To to that, use normal javascript functions like array.reduce. Or i (like some others) don't understand your question.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: Hi there @DavidGoldfarb! I am following your question, but I have problems understanding the scenario at hand. Could you please explain why @doubleunary's answer isn't valid in your system? Also to prevent an XY problem, please describe what is your end goal by using the custom function. If possible, please share a valid Wikidata link to run tests with it.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do embed this inside a more complex calculation, so I want to move it into a custom function

`query()` and `importxml()` are deterministic, so there is nothing preventing you from just wrapping them in your custom function, like this:

`=MyCustomFunction( query( importxml("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/" & $A5, "//*"), "select Col2 where Col1 = 'name in native language' and Col2 is not null", 0 ) )`

Your custom function will receive a 2D array of values as its sole argument. You can test the above formula with a simple custom function like this:

```
function MyCustomFunction(array2D) {
  return JSON.stringify(array2D);
}
```

Nevertheless, chances are that the complex calculation you refer to may be easiest to implement using a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula. They are surprisingly expressive.

Comment: This makes sense in general, as does your "XY problem"  comment. But, I don't see a clear solution.

I guess I need to fill in some more details of my "more complex calculation". Maybe you'll see a cleaner answer that I'm missing.

My importxml call is of wikidata, which returns a huge array of data. I need to call query several times on this, to extract multiple results. I'd rather not have to call importxml each time.  And, I can't put it in a separate cell because I have many calls on the sheet and no space for multiple large 2d results.